# Mulitple API in single scenario

Tags: karate, scenarios

I am trying to run mulitple `API` in single `scenario`, but I am getting below exception:

[image]

Please find my below code which includes `Background` and `Scenario`:

```
Background:
    * def kittens = read('../json/multiple.json')
    * url 'http://wwww.sample.com/' 

Scenario: Create Sample Name Record
Given path 'test'
And request kittens.a        
When method PUT
Then status 200
* def output = response
* print output

Given path 'new1/' + output.id
And request kittens.b
When method POST
Then status 200
```

I have even tried first `API` as `POST` and second `API` as `GET`, it is still giving me same `exception` as shown in above image.

Please provide suggestions.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected. The response is neither JSON or XML, but Karate still has it in the `response` variable as a string. Now it is up to you what you want to do with it. Also see other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61605535/143475