# Karate assert - I'm trying to extract a value from HTML

Tags: karate

I'm making an API call using karate that gives an HTML response (snippet below). I'm trying to extract the **value='HotelTestLondonHotel'**.  I tried to use the **Karate.extract** but I couldn't find an example of it anywhere. I know I can use JS for this in some way but I was wondering if there was an easier way?

'''

<input type='hidden' name='security_emerchant_id value='HotelTestLondonHotel'/><input type='hidden' name='XXX_IPGTRXNO_XXX' '''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/89179842ff7260b1bc299f96d0dda9ddf6afcd2e/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/extract.feature) from the Karate unit-tests:

```
Feature: karate.extract()

Background:
* def text = karate.readAsString('extract.html')

Scenario: extract first regex
* def token = karate.extract(text, 'login_form_token.+value=\\"([^\\"]+)', 1)
* match token == 'secret1'

Scenario: extract all regexes
* def tokens = karate.extractAll(text, 'login_form.?_token.+value=\\"([^\\"]+)', 1)
* match tokens == ['secret1', 'secret2']
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<form name="login_form" method="post" action="/login">
  <input type="hidden" id="login_form_token" value="secret1">
</form>
<form name="login_form2" method="post" action="/login">
  <input type="hidden" id="login_form2_token" value="secret2">
</form>
</html>
```