# Extract values from HREF URL in Karate

Tags: karate

I do have a query in Karate which is going to return the self Href URL of the object

```
"href": "https://domain.xyz/version/system/hwlayer/suppliers/supplier/locations/location/machines/machine"
```

Part of the response shall be input data for the next test. I need to be able to extract

supplier
location
machine

and they are not fixed in length. I looked up the help but couldn't find what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a `karate` question. I suggest you ask someone who knows JS or Regular Expressions for help next time. Here is one possible solution:

```
* def link = 'https://blah/suppliers/supplier/foo/location/bar/machine'
* def text1 = '/supplier/'
* def text2 = '/location/'
* def pos1 = link.lastIndexOf(text1)
* def pos2 = link.lastIndexOf(text2)
* def supplier = link.substring(pos1 + text1.length, pos2)
* match supplier == 'foo'
* def pos3 = link.lastIndexOf('/')
* def location = link.substring(pos2 + text2.length, pos3)
* match location == 'bar'
```

EDIT - also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67331307/143475