# Getting error in converting X-path to String

Tags: xml, karate

Getting a SOAP API response as a SOAP XML in Karate. I am able to print the whole response but getting error when trying to convert any XML path to String even while trying to print. I need to convert to String in order to pass it to Java Method which matches it against "**wsdl ** schema"

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO3Si.png)

[Screenshot of SOAP response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHc9H.png)

Comment: read this please and you can edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First, see if adding this line solves the problem:

```
* configure xmlNamespaceAware = true
```

This is because of an issue with Karate's XML parser, explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1587#issuecomment-1024935946

Here is one more option, convert the `response` to a string, and then do some regex extraction:

```
* string temp = responseBytes
* def extracted = karate.extract(temp, '<start>([^<]+)', 1)
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67331307/143475